# Rails 4 - how to install "jquery-ui"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui

For using jquery autocomplete plugin, I need to install **jquery-ui** gem.

So far, I had in my gemfile following:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

So I added:

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

And to `application.js` I added:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

and to `application.css`:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.ui
```

`bundle update`, restart server and:

```
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui'
```

I am using in the app also `turbolinks`. Do I miss a gem something or something in order to make **jquery-ui** work in the app?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

All jquery-related stuff in tehe Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

Comment: I belive that you need to require the gem in application.js like this: `//= require jquery.ui` or in your application.css use `*= require jquery-ui`

Answer (score 6):

In `application.css` it should be

```
 *= require jquery-ui
```

Answer (score 5):

In `application.js` you need to add:

`//= require jquery.ui.all`

or for specific components e.g.

`//= require jquery.ui.sortable`

Answer (score 2):

To update this answer, the current convention is:

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

and for css:

```
/*
*= require jquery-ui
*/
```

for specific modules:

```
//= require jquery-ui/draggable
```

[See latest docs here for more configuration options](https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails)

Answer (score 1):

You need to describe which component you want to use. You can add

application.js

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

application.css

```
*= require jquery.ui.all
```

these lines for all component