# How to install jquery-ui/datepicker in rails 4 application?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, jquery-ui-datepicker

I installed ActiveAdmin on my rails application, and now get the following error message when loading my view. It says:

```
"couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/datepicker' with type 'application/javascript'"
```

`Extracted source (around line #6):`
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag`'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

I tried the answer on [Rails 4 - how to install "jquery-ui"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803709/rails-4-how-to-install-jquery-ui)

but it didn't work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing ActiveAdmin gem, just add this to your `application.js` :

```
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
```

And in your `application.css`:

```
*= require jquery-ui/datepicker
```

When you check the view page source it should be there after restarting the server

Comment: I tried this too. But it does not work. Could it be linked to the fact that I have  both gem 'query-rails' and gem 'query-ui-rails' in my gemfile?

Comment: I've just installed fresh `rails 4.2.7` and I added gem `'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'` after that you don't need any additional gem in order to work. Jquery-UI is already installed. just add the (widget) code what I added from my answer. This is my `application.js` file :

`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
//= require_tree .`

Comment: Thanks, I realise I did not run 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'. Instead I ran 

gem 'activeadmin'

# Plus integrations with:
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan' # or cancancan
gem 'draper'
gem 'pundit'

I suppose this might be the error?

Comment: It should not. According to their github page `'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'` will be proper way of installing it for Rails 4. If you check Gemfile on their main page you will see that it has dependencies for jquery-ui, so no need to install it on top.  `gem 'jquery-ui-rails', rails_major == '3' ? '~> 4.0' : '~> 5.0'`. it also checks for rails versions as well to add other dependencies. Is it working now?

Answer (score 0):

```
gem 'just-datetime-picker'
```

Follow this https://github.com/Envek/jquery-datetimepicker-rails for it to work with ActiveAdmin

Comment: try adding `//= require jquery-ui/datepicker` in your application.js